Multiple substitutions in a table
Suppose we have a table like the following :




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
17-01
DO
22-06
DO
17-01
22-06
22-06


2
22-06
22-06
17-01
DO
22-06
09-17
09-17


3
09-17
DO
22-06
22-06
DO
17-01
17-01


4
17-01
22-06
17-01
DO
22-06
DO
22-06


5
22-06
DO
09-17
09-17
09-17
22-06
09-17


6
09-17
09-17
DO
22-06
DO
09-17
22-06



And I would like to substitute the following values more efficiently.

"09-17" ---> "07-15".
"17-01" ---> "15-23"
"22-06" ---> "20-04"

I managed to do it with the following solution (not so efficiently as it makes lot of loops)
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({B2:G6},"09-17","07-15"),"17-01","15-23"),"22-06","20-04"))

I was wondering how this can be done more efficiently when the dimensions of the table are too large.
Any idea how to limit unnecessary repetitions?

Will this data be continuously updated? If not, I would just to a find and replace.

Put your substitutions in your sheet, for example, in Columns I and J:




A     
B     
C     
D     
E     
F     
G     
H
I      
J     




1
17-01
DO
22-06
DO
17-01
22-06
22-06

Find
Replace


2
22-06
22-06
17-01
DO
22-06
09-17
09-17

09-17
07-15


3
09-17
DO
22-06
22-06
DO
17-01
17-01

17-01
15-23


4
17-01
22-06
17-01
DO
22-06
DO
22-06

22-06
20-04


5
22-06
DO
09-17
09-17
09-17
22-06
09-17





6
09-17
09-17
DO
22-06
DO
09-17
22-06






Use the following formula. You can constrain the ranges if you prefer. eg. I2:J4 instead of I2:J, or A1:G700 instead of A1:G
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:G, I2:J, 2, 0), A1:G))

ARRAYFORMULA  IFNA  VLOOKUP

You could alternatively hard-code the values if you prefer:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:G,
   {"09-17","07-15"; "17-01","15-23"; "22-06","20-04"},
   2, 0), A1:G))


Faster Approach
The following approach is about 50% faster than the VLOOKUP approach and about 2x faster than the nested SUBSTITUTE approach.  Depending on the size of the source range, the speed difference may not be noticeable:
ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(A1:G="09-17","07-15",
    IF(A1:G="17-01","15-23",
      IF(A1:G="22-06","20-04", A1:G))))

ARRAYFORMULA  IF
